# Rellenar TableView desde un JSON

Tags: json, swift3, uitableviewcontroller

soy un novato total en swift y ni las cosas más simples soy capaz de hacerlas. Por ejemplo, quisiera mostrar en un table view una lista de nombres de colegios que me vienen en un archivo JSON, pero no soy capaz de hacerlo.

Concretamente, mi JSON devuelve lo siguiente:

```
[{"id_centro":"3","0":"3","nombre":"Colegio Vistarreal","1":"Colegio Vistarreal"},{"id_centro":"1","0":"1","nombre":"IES ITC Sistemas","1":"IES ITC Sistemas"}]
```

Y tengo implementado mi UITableViewController de la siguiente manera:

```
import UIKit

class TCentrosController: UITableViewController {

    var centrosList = [String] ()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        Dologin()

    }


    func Dologin(){

        let url = URL (string: "https://neton.es/WS_neton/lista_centros.php")

        let session = URLSession.shared

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest (url: url!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {

            (data, response, error) in
            guard let _:Data = data else{

                return
            }

            do{

                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as! [[String:Any]]

                if json.isEmpty{

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {

                        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Atención", message: "No hay centros disponibles", preferredStyle: .alert)


                        let yesAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default)
                        { (action ) -> Void in
                            print("Centros no operativos")
                        }

                        alertController.addAction(yesAction)

                        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

                    }

                    return

                //Si el json no está vacío, sigue por aquí
                }else{

                    let nombreCentro:String = json[1]["nombre"] as! String             
                    self.centrosList.append(nombreCentro)

                }
            }

            catch{
                print("Error")
            }


        })
        task.resume()

    }


  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return centrosList.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "centros_lista", for: indexPath) as! CeldaCentrosTableViewCell

        cell.labelCell.text = centrosList[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
}
```

Pero no me devuelve nada por pantalla. De hecho, si hago un print(centrosList.count) me dice que cero.

Como veis, no tengo mucha idea y seguro tengo más de un fallo que no soy capaz de ver. Por cierto, estoy programando con swift 3

Gracias, cualquier ayuda me vendrá bien

Answer (score 0):

Al final he podido encontrar la solución y la dejo por aquí por si a alguien más le llegara a suceder algo parecido.
Simplemente me había faltado refrescar mi array, lo cual se consigue añadiendo la línea:

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

y todo ellos hacerlo en un hilo que lo proceso. Quedando entonces así el código:

```
}else{
                    //Hilo que procesará los datos
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {

                        //ciclo que recorre el json
                        for item in json {

                            //en variables metemos los datos que nos interesan del json
                            let nombreCentro:String = item["nombre"] as! String

                            //Añadir los datos del json a su array correspondiente
                            self.centrosList.append(nombreCentro)

                        }

                        //Refrescar los datos de la tabla
                        self.tableView.reloadData()

                    }
```

Saludos!

Comment: respuesta, tenía el mismo problema y me lo has solucionado. ;-)
Juan

Comment: Me alegro que te funcionara!